# How do I send a message to Telegram that includes a button that prompts the user to forward the message?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Many Telegram bots (e.g., @youtube) have a button you can click on to forward messages sent by the bot. When the user clicks on this button, Telegram opens a contact list that lets the user choose who to forward the message to.

How can I send a button like this? The closest thing I can find is [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage) but that expects `chat_id` target ID as a required parameter. But I won't have this target ID until the user selects who they want to forward to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to share your content to specific chats, you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

If your bot has `inline_mode` enabled you can share content via a button that opens a `inline_query` in the chat selected. Basically, this is how @youtube bot works. To use this method you need to send an inline button with `switch_inline_query` as a field ([documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton)).

Example in Javascript:

```js
bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, 'Share:', {
    reply_markup: {
        inline_keyboard: [[{
            text: 'Share with your friends',
            switch_inline_query: 'share'
        }]]
    }
})
```

This is the same example I use in my bot [@livecoinbot](https://t.me/livecoinbot), set a bitcoin address and use the share button.

**Option 2**

You can create a normal inline button or just simply send a link in a normal message, that will prompt the telegram client to share the content. Here is how you do it:

`https://t.me/share/url?url=[url-to-send-here]&text=[text]`

Example: [Click here](https://t.me/share/url?url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491201/how-do-i-send-a-message-to-telegram-that-includes-a-button-that-prompts-the-user#&text=Stackoverflow%20Answer%20By%20@kamikazechaser)